Having trouble plotting mean in ggplot barplot
I have a dataset with columns including animal id, treatment, sex, and mean speed. I attempted to make a ggplot barplot of the mean of the mean speed vs treatment split by sex (shown below). (BTW the mean speed is for each animal, and I want to plot the mean of all the animals in a given treatment/sex). My plot does not seem to be putting in the mean though.
I know that I could get the mean using dplyr and then put that into the plot, but I was hoping I could just have ggplot do it (if there is a reason I shouldn't do this, I'd be interested in learning why).
NMXDR_OF <- read_csv("~/Desktop/R Files/5_3_24_OF_NMXDR_FinalData.csv")

ggplot(data = NMXDR_OF, mapping = aes(x=Treatment, y="Mean speed", fill = Treatment)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="summary", fun="mean") +  
  facet_wrap("Sex")+ 
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1) +  
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se) 

When I do this, the mean and the error bars are not plotted though (https://i.sstatic.net/8PvvynTK.png). I made sure that my variable "mean speed" is numeric.

y="Mean speed" is wrong, this is not mapping a variable from the data. It is mapping all the y-values to a category called "Mean speed". You can see this on the y-axis. There is no standard deviation of this category, which is why the error bars are not working. I recommend using variable names without spaces, then setting the axis labels using + labs(y = "Mean speed"). Alternatively, don't use "Mean speed" with " quotes, but using backticks \Mean speed``

Related: Difference between backticks and quotes in aes function in ggplot
